# MongoDB Shell Command for updating particular field(s) in Array of SubDocuments

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, asp.net-core-3.1

Pretty new to Mongo, not sure if I am overthinking what I am trying to do but I'm riding the struggle bus for making an update to a document.

This is essentially the schema/example for a car document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60a67081e2692669d50f3de9"
    },
    "modelNumber": 0,
    "vin": "9876543210",
    "persons": [
        {
            "ids": [
                {
                    "value": "696969",
                    "type": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "2850d92c-3849-4d81-a764-4deecd02cd81",
                    "type": "type2"
                }
            ],
            "isPrimaryOwner": true,
            "isInsured": false
        },
        {
            "ids": [
                {
                    "value": "696969",
                    "type": "type1"
                }
            ],
            "isPrimaryOwner": true,
            "isInsured": true
        },
        {
            "ids": [
                {
                    "value": "743743",
                    "type": "type1"
                }
            ],
            "isPrimaryOwner": true,
            "isInsured": false
        }
    ]
}
```

In this instance I have a car and an array of Person SubDocuments. I am trying to create a query where, given the example above, if I see multiple persons with the same id (in this case '696969') in their individual id array I want to update the 'isPrimaryOwner' for all of those Person SubDocuments to 'false' (I know this looks like a data quality issue but bear with me)

I can easily update all of the persons in the array or a single one of them but am having a hard time with using an array filter to only update the 2 that I want to update (using above as the example)

**Mongo Shell:**
 `db.Cars.updateMany({vin: "9876543210", "persons.ids.value": "696969", "persons.ids.type": "type1"}, {$set: {"persons.$[myIndex].isPrimaryOwner": false}}, {arrayFilters: [{"myIndex": [0]}]`

For the 'myIndex' variable I have 0 in there for now to try and see if it would update the first element in the array. It does not; in the shell I get this response:

```
{ acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0 }
```

It looks like it is able to identify the Document I want given the filter criteria but doesn't look like it can find what I want it to update.

I feel like I am missing something fundamental. Maybe because my `Persons` subdocuments don't have an _id field that I may need for better indexing?

I'm hoping that once I figure out what is wrong with the Shell command I will be able to translate that into what I need to do in the C# code with the MongoDriver.

Anyone dealt with a situation like this before? Maybe because I got an array in an array situation might be causing me additional complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe the following update command would do:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        vin: "9876543210"
    },
    {
        $set: { "persons.$[p].isPrimaryOwner": false }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{
            "p.ids": { $elemMatch: { type: "type1", value: "696969" } }
        }]
    }
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/89pBgZGtPRL

Comment: OOOOOh MongoPlayground this is awesome! Thanks a ton. I wasn't sure how strict the <field> section was for the arrayFilters, makes sense now that I read it.

I'll give it a go and see what happens!

Comment: hmmm ... seems that when I update the query and use the more complex model, even in the Playground, it doesn't work for whatever reason. This is super strange

Comment: does your `id` object have more fields than type and value? if so, the array filter needs to be modified.

Comment: Unfortunitly, no. There are no additional fields in the `id` object. There are more in the `persons` object but that shouldn't matter as there are more fields in the car.persons example as well.

Comment: Ok figured out the issue. The order of the fields matter. They have to match the document. The more complex version has `value` followed by `type`. Once I swapped the field positions in the arrayFilters it worked.

I REALLY hate that order matters. I wonder if there is a better way to write the query?

Comment: @Schanckopotamus yes there is a better way and i've updated my answer. that should do the trick.

Comment: Oh yeah, that worked. That is a subtle difference I am going to have to look more into, `$eq` vs `$elemMatch`. Thanks a TON!

Comment: @Schanckopotamus elemMatch matches fields individually while eq tries to match an exact object.